# One Splitter to resize 4 panels jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, resize, splitter

I want to do the following:

[image]

"**+**" in the center is **splitter**, which can move **both directions**, with this "+" you will be able to **resize** those 4 panels at the same time or hide 2 of them etc. I'm new in js and **jQuery**, can you please give me some **tips** how to do this or give me some quick **demo**?

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: My approach in the past was to have a small crosshair imageat the intersection (I guess it could be as big as you show) and set this image to be draggable. Upon drop, the panels are resized based upon its new position.